# Why isn't Hasura generating queries for tables in version 2?

Tags: hasura, hasura-docker

I see "table_name_connection" query instead of "table_name" in "query_root" section. The same hash appears instead of numeric IDs. Everything works in the first version, but this version is already deprecated.

Has anyone solved this problem?

MacOS, docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.6'
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:12
    restart: always
    volumes:
    - ./database:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
    - 5432:5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: ${PROJECT_NAME}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${ADMIN_PASSWORD}
  graphql-engine:
    image: hasura/graphql-engine:v2.0.9
    restart: always
    volumes:
    - ./database/hasura/metadata:/hasura-metadata
    - ./database/hasura/migrations:/hasura-migrations
    ports:
    - 4321:8080
    depends_on:
    - "postgres"
    environment:
      HASURA_GRAPHQL_METADATA_DATABASE_URL: postgres://postgres:${ADMIN_PASSWORD}@postgres:5432/${PROJECT_NAME}
      HASURA_GRAPHQL_DATABASE_URL: postgres://postgres:${ADMIN_PASSWORD}@postgres:5432/${PROJECT_NAME}
      # HASURA_GRAPHQL_DATABASE_URL: postgres://postgres:${ADMIN_PASSWORD}@postgres:5432/${PROJECT_NAME}
      HASURA_GRAPHQL_ENABLE_CONSOLE: ${DEV_MODE}
      HASURA_GRAPHQL_DEV_MODE: ${DEV_MODE}
      HASURA_GRAPHQL_ENABLED_LOG_TYPES: ${HASURA_LOGS}
      HASURA_GRAPHQL_ADMIN_SECRET: ${ADMIN_PASSWORD}
```

[image: table]
[image: database]
[image: console]

Answer (score 1):

You have enabled the relay api toggle:

[image: Hasura console, showing the relay api toggle enabled]